# Is there a less vertical way to do a select case in python other than elifs?

Tags: python, select, flow-control

So I can do a Select Case in python with

```
if integer == 1:
  case0()
elif integer == 2:
  case2()
elif integer == 3:
  case3()
....
elif integer == N:
  caseN()
```

Some times I use a list using the index as a selector.

```
selectCase = [case0(),case1(),case3(),...,caseN()] [N]
```

But this makes that each item in the list to be processed before selected right?

So I was wondering if there other ways to do this without spanning so much vertically to control what code is executed.
Are there maybe ways to jump to parts of the code? Maybe I don't want to solve a function but just skip some lines.

Thanks

Comment: You could do `selectCase = [case0,case1,case3,...,caseN][N]()`

Answer (score 3):

One way is to take advantage of the fact that you can store functions in dictionaries:

```
functions = {
    1: case1,
    2: case2,
    ...
}

functions[case]()
```

Notice I'm not using the parenthesis in the dictionary. In your example in the list you would storing the result of the function not the function itself.

Comment: for sequential numbers starting at 0 or 1, just use a list. For starting at 1, insert a `None` at the start to cover `0`.

Comment: I was just using arbitrary numbers, I'm not sure if the OP's use case is actually that simple.

Comment: From the queston: *Some times I use a list using the index as a selector*

Comment: This is a good solution. Only issue is if each function needs different arguments, so I would need something like:

 [HERE](http://repl.it/BCwN) 


Since I was basically trying to select which code runs like you do with elifs. As long as the arguments are calculated variables, this only takes the extra time to build the lists versus elifs, I think.

Comment: @IanAuld 
Indeed I was trying to do flow control

Comment: By the way is [option1, option2][condition] a good practice?

Thanks